# Why do I get a "not well-formed" error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, firefox, rss

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    /*========*\
    | RSS feed |
    \*========*/

    //Feed address
    var feed = "http://www.kelvinshadewing.net/feed.xml";

    $.ajax(feed, {
        accepts:{ xml: "application/rss+xml"},
        datatype: "xml",
        success: function(data){
            $(data).find("item").each(function(){
                var el = $(this);

                console.log("----------------");
                console.log("Title: " + el.find("title").text());
                console.log("Link: " + el.find("link").text());
                console.log("Description: " + el.find("description").text());
            });
        }
    });
});
```

For some reason, it keeps giving me an error that just says "not well-formed" and in the section that says where the error is, it says `<unknown>:1:116`, basically pointing to a position on a line that doesn't exist. Does anyone know what this is? As far as I can tell, everything else in the code is correct; in fact, apart from my own feed address, this code is copy-pasted from [this tutorial](http://www.raymondcamden.com/2015/12/08/parsing-rss-feeds-in-javascript-options/).

Does anyone have any idea what this error means? I'm using Firefox, and my feed format is XML.

Comment: You're probably getting an error because you're trying to make a cross-domain request to a server that does not respond with CORS headers.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, removing the domain and changing the `feed` variable to just `feed.xml`, it's working properly now. That might have been the cross-domain issue that was mentioned, but it's all on the same domain, so I don't really know. Either way, it works now, so anyone else reading this should try changing their feed URL to a local one.